# Testing strategy, stub, mock, prophecy, what?

Tags: 8, testing

I have a helper class in my module that facilitates in creating Drupal user accounts *based* on some information returned from an external system.

What I would like to do is add tests for this class.

Here is the class in question:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\netforum_auth\Netforum;

use Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\user\UserInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Unicode;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

/**
 * Class NetforumAccountManager.
 *
 * @package Drupal\netforum_auth\Netforum
 */
class NetforumAccountManager implements NetforumAccountManagerInterface {

  /**
   * The entity type manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * The language manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface
   */
  protected $languageManager;

  /**
   * The logger.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactoryInterface
   */
  protected $logger;

  /**
   * The Netforum client.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\netforum_auth\Netforum\NetforumClientInterface
   */
  protected $client;

  /**
   * Class constructor.
   */
  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager, LoggerChannelFactoryInterface $logger_channel_factory, NetforumClientInterface $client) {
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
    $this->languageManager = $language_manager;
    $this->logger = $logger_channel_factory;
    $this->client = $client;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function createUser(\stdClass $netforum_account) : int {
    $user = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('user')->create();
    $langcode = $this->languageManager->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
    $email_address = $netforum_account->result->Customer->cst_eml_address_dn;
    $customer_key = $netforum_account->result->Customer->cst_key;
    $customer_number = $netforum_account->result->Customer->cst_recno;

    $parts = explode('@', $email_address);
    $drupal_username = $parts[0] . $customer_number;
    $password = user_password(15);

    $user->enforceIsNew();
    $user->setUsername($drupal_username);
    $user->setPassword($password);
    $user->setEmail($email_address);
    $user->set("init", $email_address);
    $user->set("langcode", $langcode);
    $user->set("preferred_langcode", $langcode);
    $user->set("preferred_admin_langcode", $langcode);
    $user->set("preferred_admin_langcode", $langcode);
    $user->set("field_netforum_customer_key", $customer_key);
    $user->set("field_netforum_customer_recno", $customer_number);
    $user->activate();
    $user->save();

    // Set the roles.
    $account = User::load($user->id());
    $this->updateUserRoles($account, $netforum_account);

    return $user->id();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function updateUser(UserInterface $account, \stdClass $netforum_account) {
    // @todo: This will be filled in later if they do any profile related stuff.

    // Update the roles.
    $this->updateUserRoles($account, $netforum_account);
  }

  /**
   * Wipe and rebuild a users roles to be in-sync with Netforum memberships.
   */
  public function updateUserRoles(UserInterface $account, $netforum_account) {
    $netforum_role = $netforum_account->result->Individual->ind_int_code;
    $membership_info = $this->getActiveMembershipsForCustomer($netforum_account);
    $member_types = $this->getActiveMemberTypesFromCustomerMembership($membership_info);

    // Remove previous roles, for security reasons.
    $previous_roles = $account->getRoles(TRUE);

    foreach ($previous_roles as $role) {
      // Don't remove Administrator if it was previously set.
      if ($role !== 'administrator') {
        $account->removeRole($role);
      }
    }

    $roles = [];

    // Staff is an actual user role, not a membership type
    if ($netforum_role == 'Staff') {
      $roles[] = 'content_editor';
    }

    foreach ($member_types as $role_name) {
      $roles[] = $this->mapToDrupalRole($role_name);
    }

    // At the least, we should assign a boilerplate role.
    if (empty($roles)) {
      $account->addRole('netforum_member');
    }

    foreach ($roles as $role) {
      $account->addRole($role);
    }

    $account->save();
  }

  /**
   * Maps netforum membership types to local Drupal roles.
   */
  public function mapToDrupalRole(string $membership_type) : string {
    switch (Unicode::strtoupper($membership_type)) {
      case 'CARRIER DIVISION':
        $role = 'carrier_division';
        break;

      case 'RAIL DIVISION':
        $role = 'rail_division';
        break;

      case 'SUPPLIER DIVISION':
        $role = 'supplier_division';
        break;

      case 'ASSOCIATE':
        $role = 'associate';
        break;

      default:
        $role = 'netforum_member';
        break;
    }

    return $role;
  }

  /**
   * Returns all membership information for a given netforum user.
   *
   * I really dislike this call because it returns just a string of XML instead
   * of the responses we are used to receiving. It is a custom SQL call done by
   * using ExecuteMethod, a unique API method in Netforum.
   */
  public function getActiveMembershipsForCustomer(\stdClass $netforum_account) {
    $customer_key = $netforum_account->result->Customer->cst_key;

    $arguments = [
      'serviceName' => 'GetActiveMembershipsForCustomer',
      'methodName' => 'GetActiveMemberships',
      'parameters' => [
        'Parameter' => [
          'Name' => 'cst_key',
          'Value' => $customer_key,
        ],
      ],
    ];

    $response = $this->client->request('ExecuteMethod', [$arguments]);

    $parts = explode('-', $customer_key);
    $last_segment = end($parts);

    if ($response->error) {
      $message = $response->result->Message . ' Customer key ending in: @key.';
      $this->logger->get('netforum_auth')->error($message, ['@key' => $last_segment]);
    }
    elseif (!$response->result) {
      $message = 'Customer key ending in: @key has no membership information.';
      $this->logger->get('netforum_auth')->info($message, ['@key' => $last_segment]);
    }
    else {
      // This entire result is returned as an xml string, convert it.
      $xml = simplexml_load_string($response->result->any);
      $json = json_encode($xml);
      $response->result = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    }

    return $response;
  }

  /**
   * Filters out active roles from the membership information.
   */
  public function getActiveMemberTypesFromCustomerMembership($membership_information) : array {
    $roles = [];

    if ($membership_information->result) {
      foreach ($membership_information->result['Membership'] as $membership) {
        if ($membership['MbrStatus'] == 'Active') {
          $roles[] = $membership['MbrType'];
        }
      }
    }

    return $roles;
  }

}
```

How can I approach testing this class? My first thought was I needed to mock the method that makes an API call and have it return an array like the real call would do (passed to `getActiveMemberTypesFromCustomerMembership`).

I can't quite figure out though how to do this in code. Here is where I started:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Tests\netforum_auth\Kernel;

use Drupal\netforum_auth\Netforum\NetforumAccountManager;
use Drupal\Tests\token\Kernel\KernelTestBase;
use org\bovigo\vfs\vfsStream;
use org\bovigo\vfs\visitor\vfsStreamStructureVisitor;

/**
 * Class UserCreateTest
 *
 * @package Drupal\Tests\netforum_auth\Kernel
 * @group netforum_auth
 */
class UserCreateTest extends KernelTestBase {

  /**
   * Modules to enable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  public static $modules = ['system', 'user', 'netforum_auth'];

  protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    // create roles
  }

  public function testUserIsCreated() {
    $netforum_wsdl_response = new \stdClass();
    $netforum_wsdl_response->result = new \stdClass();
    $netforum_wsdl_response->result->Customer = new \stdClass();
    $netforum_wsdl_response->result->Customer->cst_eml_address_dn = 'zztesting@example.comzz';
    $netforum_wsdl_response->result->Customer->cst_key = '123-456-789';
    $netforum_wsdl_response->result->Customer->cst_recno = '123456';

    $result = new \stdClass();
    $result->response = [
      'Membership' => [
        0 => [
          'MbrStatus' => 'Active',
          'MbrType' => 'Associate'
        ]
      ]
    ];

    $prophecy = $this->prophesize(NetforumAccountManager::CLASS);
    $prophecy->getActiveMembershipsForCustomer($netforum_wsdl_response)->willReturn($result);
    $netforum_account_manager = $prophecy->reveal();

    $uid = $netforum_account_manager->createUser($netforum_wsdl_response);
    // check $uid is a User
    // check role(s)
  }

}
```

But I get this error:

```
Method call:
  - createUser(stdClass:00000000584be36000000000303910bf Object (
    'result' => stdClass:00000000584be19c00000000303910bf Object (
        'Customer' => stdClass:00000000584be05a00000000303910bf Object (
            'cst_eml_address_dn' => 'zztesting@example.comzz'
            'cst_key' => '123-456-789'
            'cst_recno' => '123456'
        )
    )
))
on Double\Drupal\iana_netforum_auth\Netforum\NetforumAccountManager\P1 was not expected, expected calls were:
  - getActiveMembershipsForCustomer(exact(stdClass:00000000584be36000000000303910bf Object (
    'result' => stdClass:00000000584be19c00000000303910bf Object (
        'Customer' => stdClass:00000000584be05a00000000303910bf Object (
            'cst_eml_address_dn' => 'zztesting@example.comzz'
            'cst_key' => '123-456-789'
            'cst_recno' => '123456'
        )
    )
)))
```

This is the first time I have tried this. Should the two `get` calls be moved out to a new class, and mock the one method? Then test the actual class here?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I wound up refactoring the class to decouple the dependency on the `$client` service and moved the API call in this class to an external class. I did not need any mocks and from there just tested my class with dummy data. The class I am testing only assumes now that a Drupal user object or response from a Netforum call is passed in, or both, making it testable (or, more easy to test) than before.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Tests\netforum_auth\Kernel;

use Drupal\Tests\token\Kernel\KernelTestBase;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Drupal\simpletest\UserCreationTrait;

/**
 * Class NetformAccountManagerTest.
 *
 * @package Drupal\Tests\netforum_auth\Kernel
 * @group netforum_auth
 */
class NetformAccountManagerTest extends KernelTestBase {

  use UserCreationTrait {
    createRole as drupalCreateRole;
  }

  /**
   * Modules to enable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  public static $modules = ['system', 'user', 'field', 'text', 'netforum_auth'];

  /**
   * The NetforumAccountManager service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\netforum_auth\Netforum\NetforumAccountManager
   */
  protected $accountManager;

  /**
   * Holds a simluated NetforumClient response about an individual in Netforum.
   *
   * @var \stdClass
   */
  protected $dummy_account;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    $this->installSchema('system', 'sequences');
    $this->installEntitySchema('user');

    $this->drupalCreateRole([], 'associate', 'Associate');
    $this->drupalCreateRole([], 'member', 'Member');
    $this->drupalCreateRole([], 'content_editor', 'Content Editor');

    $field = FieldStorageConfig::create(array(
      'field_name' => 'field_netforum_customer_key',
      'entity_type' => 'user',
      'type' => 'text',
    ));

    $field->save();

    $field = FieldStorageConfig::create(array(
      'field_name' => 'field_netforum_customer_recno',
      'entity_type' => 'user',
      'type' => 'text',
    ));

    $field->save();

    FieldConfig::create([
      'field_name' => 'field_netforum_customer_key',
      'entity_type' => 'user',
      'label' => 'Customer Key',
      'bundle' => 'user',
    ])->save();

    FieldConfig::create([
      'field_name' => 'field_netforum_customer_recno',
      'entity_type' => 'user',
      'label' => 'Customer Number',
      'bundle' => 'user',
    ])->save();

    $this->accountManager = $this->container->get('netforum_auth.netforum_account_manager');

    $netforum_wsdl_response = new \stdClass();
    $netforum_wsdl_response->result = new \stdClass();
    $netforum_wsdl_response->result->Customer = new \stdClass();
    $netforum_wsdl_response->result->Individual = new \stdClass();
    $netforum_wsdl_response->result->Individual->ind_int_code = 'Staff';
    $netforum_wsdl_response->result->Customer->cst_eml_address_dn = 'zztesting@example.comzz';
    $netforum_wsdl_response->result->Customer->cst_key = '123-456-789';
    $netforum_wsdl_response->result->Customer->cst_recno = '123456';

    $netforum_wsdl_response->result->Membership = [
      0 => [
        'MbrStatus' => 'Active',
        'MbrType' => 'Associate',
      ],
      1 => [
        'MbrStatus' => 'Inactive',
        'MbrType' => 'At-Large Motor Carrier Division',
      ],
      2 => [
        'MbrStatus' => '',
        'MbrType' => 'At-Large Rail Division',
      ],
      3 => [
        'MbrStatus' => 'Active',
        'MbrType' => 'Member',
      ],
    ];

    $this->dummy_account = $netforum_wsdl_response;
  }

  /**
   * Test that a user is created with the correct roles.
   *
   * @covers \Drupal\netforum_auth\Netforum\NetforumAccountManager::createUser
   */
  public function testUserIsCreated() {
    $uid = $this->accountManager->createUser($this->dummy_account);
    $this->assertNotEquals(0, $uid);

    $account = User::load($uid);
    $roles = $account->getRoles(TRUE);

    // Our Drupal user should have 3 roles, not 2.
    $this->assertContains('associate', $roles);
    $this->assertContains('member', $roles);
    $this->assertContains('content_editor', $roles);
    $this->assertNotContains('administrator', $roles);
  }

  /**
   * Tests the user role mapping method.
   *
   * Unrecognized roles should be set as netforum_member.
   *
   * @covers \Drupal\netforum_auth\Netforum\NetforumAccountManager::mapToDrupalRole
   */
  public function testUserRoleMapping() {
    $role = $this->accountManager->mapToDrupalRole('associate');
    $this->assertEquals('associate', $role);

    $role = $this->accountManager->mapToDrupalRole('MEMBER');
    $this->assertEquals('member', $role);

    $role = $this->accountManager->mapToDrupalRole('AT-LARGE MoToR cARRIER DIVISIOn');
    $this->assertEquals('at_large_motor_division', $role);

    $role = $this->accountManager->mapToDrupalRole('DUMMY TYPE');
    $this->assertEquals('netforum_member', $role);

    $role = $this->accountManager->mapToDrupalRole('Staff');
    $this->assertNotEquals('administrator', $role);
  }

  /**
   * Tests that we get the correct types that we expect.
   *
   * @covers \Drupal\netforum_auth\Netforum\NetforumAccountManager::getMembershipTypes
   */
  public function testMembershipTypeParser() {
    $types = $this->accountManager->getMembershipTypes($this->dummy_account);
    $this->assertEquals($types, ['Associate', 'Member']);
  }

}
```

I'm not sure if this is 100% great approach, but my class and its couple of methods are now covered by tests. To supplement this test, I also want to write a behavior test with Behat to simulate a user actually logging in - the results should be exactly the same.

Would love to know more though about how others are testing their own services or classes.